# scrollTop() not working in Mozilla Firefox and IE?

Tags: javascript, scrolltop

I want to use scrollTop() method, look like:

```
function scroll() {
    i=$("body").scrollTop();
    $("body").scrollTop(++i);
}
```

but it isn't work in Mozilla and IE.
How can i do that with Mozilla and IE?

```
$("body").scrollTop=99;
```

not work too.

Comment: `scrollTop()` takes the window, not the body.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("html, body").scrollTop(99)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">    
    $(window).load(function(){
      $("html, body").scrollTop(0);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please document how his cdoe answers the question.